# Looping through list of objects created by createEntry() and editing their properties before doing submitChange()

Tags: odata, sapui5

Good afternoon fellow developers,

I have come across a scenario where I found myself needing to retrieve the list of pending changes from my model and editing a specific property of those entries before sending them to my back-end.

These are new entities I created using the `createEntry()` method of the OData model v2. But, at the time of creation of said entities, I do not possess the value I need to add to them yet. This is the list of entities I retrieve by using the `getPendingChanges()` method on my model:

[image: list of entry objects created by createEntry() method]

What I need to do is to loop through each of these newly created entities and set a specific property into them before actually sending them to my back-end with the `submitChanges()` method. Bare in mind that these are entry objects created by the `createEntry()` method and exist only in my front-end until I am able to submit them with success.

Any ideas that might point me in the right direction? I look forward to reading from you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue in the following way:

```
var oPendingChanges = this.model.getPendingChanges();
var aPathsPendingChanges = $.map(oPendingChanges, function(value, index) { return [index];});

aPathsPendingChanges.forEach(sPath => oModel.setProperty("/" + sPath + "/PropertyX","valueFGO"));
```

The first two instructions retrieve the entire list of pendingChanges objects and then builds an array of paths to each individual entry. I then use that array of paths to loop through my list of pending changes and edit into the property I want in each iteration of the loop. Special thanks to the folks at answers.sap for the guidance!